# Cannot get Keycloak Tomcat 7 adapter to work (version 3.4.3.Final)

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat7, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot 1.5.2 Web App packaged as a .war hosted on an Apache Tomcat 7.0.68.

I want to use the Keycloak Tomcat Adapter but I encounter HTTP 401 returns on every endpoints included in the configuration...
I am using the 3.4.3.Final version.

I have read the doc @ http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/tomcat-adapter.html.

**Facts:**

- The users, groups, roles, realm, client etc. exist in the main Keycloak configuration.
- Downloaded https://downloads.jboss.org/keycloak/3.4.3.Final/adapters/keycloak-oidc/keycloak-tomcat7-adapter-dist-3.4.3.Final.zip and extracted under `<tomcat_folder>/lib/`
- Created a `META-INF/context.xml` file with :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Context path="/my-app">
      <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve"/>
  </Context>
  ```
- Created a `WEB-INF/keycloak.json` file with :

  ```
  {
     "realm" : "my_realm",
     "resource" : "my_client",
     "principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
     "truststore" : "/my_path/keycloak-truststore.jks",
     "ssl-required" : "external",

     "truststore-password" : "my_password",
     "credentials" : {
         "secret" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
     "auth-server-url" : "http://<keycloak_server>.fr:8443/auth"
  }
  ```
- Created a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file with :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">
  <display-name>my-app</display-name>
  <module-name>my-app</module-name>

  <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>my_realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>

  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <url-pattern>/customer/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>uma_authorization</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-role>
      <role-name>uma_authorization</role-name>
  </security-role>
  ```

(simple test with uma_authorization, role that every user has)

**Conclusion :** HTTP 200 on every endpoints except /customer/* where I get HTTP 401.

**Interesting thing**, in debug, I have detected that the variable `account` is always `null` on the line 61 from the `CatalinaSessionTokenStore` class (from Tomcat Keycloak Adapter dependency) :

```
Session catalinaSession = request.getSessionInternal(false);
if (catalinaSession == null) return;
SerializableKeycloakAccount account = (SerializableKeycloakAccount) catalinaSession.getSession().getAttribute(SerializableKeycloakAccount.class.getName());
if (account == null) {
    return;
}
(... next lines are to control the content of the Keycloak context)
```

Nothing in the Tomcat log even with TRACE level activated.

Did I forget something to configure ? Is it a bug ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found. In my keycloak.json, switch from :

```
"auth-server-url" : "http://<keycloak_server>.fr:8443/auth"
```

To :

```
"auth-server-url" : "https://<keycloak_server>.fr:8443/auth"
```

No log, no error...
It's a pity that the Keycloak adapters configuration is so badly documented and logging almost non-existent...

Comment: Don't just complain. Help improving Keycloak and contribute code or documentation by doing a PR. That's how OSS work. You're welcome!

Comment: @dasniko you are right. If I have time, I would like to improve this...

Comment: keycloak user jboss logging, have to redirect to tomcat with CATALINA_OPTS="-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk"