# Tomcat-KeyCloak: FAIL -Deployed application at context path but context failed to start

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, tomcat7, keycloak

I'm trying to authenticate a Tomcat7 webapp (Server 1) using KeyCloak 4.0.0 (deployed on Server 2)

I've followed the instructions listed [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/tomcat-adapter.html#_tomcat_adapter), but each time I try to develop a WAR on Tomcat (Server 1) I got this error:

```
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /my _path but context failed to start
```

corresponding to this Exception in Tomcat:

```
Apr 24, 2018 5:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate MessageBodyReader
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:760)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:742)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registerProvider(ResteasyDeployment.java:505)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:305)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1747)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:457)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:653)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal to inject a message body into a singleton into public org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider(org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper,org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.Annotations[])
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.injectableArguments(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.getProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1038)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:478)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:756)
    ... 49 more
```

Maybe my issue is somehow related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391338/cannot-get-keycloak-tomcat-7-adapter-to-work-version-3-4-3-final).

What's puzzles me is that such error does **not** seem to depend by my WAR application. No matters which WAR I  try to deploy on Tomcat, I always have this error, even if the WAR is NOT using KeyCloak. I mean: even if my WAR does not contain any "security-constraint" element nor "filter" nor "role-name", no other stuff regarding KeyCloak (i.e. all my pages are public), 
I got always the FAIL error when deploying it.

This seems related to the installation of the *keycloak-tomcat7-adapter-dist.zip* JARs into the Tomcat *lib* directory, as depicted [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/tomcat-adapter.html#_tomcat_adapter). If I just remove all these JARs from the *lib* folder, then I solve the problem (but of course in such scenario I can't use KeyCloak authentication).

Am I missing something (maybe the WAR and KeyCloak must live in the same Tomcat server), or is there a bug in the Keycloak tomcat 7 adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

In my case the issue was generated by a conflict in the **RESTEasy libraries**: the POM file of my WebApp was importing this version of *resteasy-jackson-provider* libraries:

```
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0.GA</version>
```

while the KeyCloak Tomcat Adapter was using these JARs:

```
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.9.jar
```

From [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider/2.2.0.GA) I understood the 2.2.0.GA was wrapping version 1.6.3 of the same libraries. Probably for this reason my classes where compiled using the old libraries (1.6.3) and then deployed on a Tomcat using a newer version of the same libraries (1.9.9, coming from the adapter), and this triggered the error.

Therefore I browsed for a *resteasy-jackson-provider* package bundling exactly the 1.9.9 version of the target libraries, like this [one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider/2.3.10.Final), and I solved the problem loading them also in my POM file:

```
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
<version>2.3.10.Final</version>
```

Hope this can help somebody else!